# Is there a way to use Apple Earpods (wired) so the microphone works in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, microphone, earbuds

I have a pair of Apple Earpods (their wired earbuds). I have a headphone splitter that splits the speaker and mic lines into their own connectors.

I am using a custom-built PC. The motherboard is an [ASRock B250M-HDV](https://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/B250M-HDV/).

With the Apple Earpods, the mic does not work on my Arch Linux install, but it does on Windows. Based on my research this is because Apple is using different wiring than is standard.

The suggested solution I have found is to buy Apple’s 3.5mm to USB C adapter and use that instead.

I don't want to do that because I know it can be done through software. Is there a driver or something I can install on my Linux box to get them to work?

Comment: What is the schematic of your splitter? What is the schematic of your mic-in (or line-in?) jack that you're connecting it to? Have you successfully used any other mic on that input port? Have you successfully used the splitter with a different headset and had the mic work?

Comment: All I can say is that if it works under Windows, it is _not_ a hardware issue (like different wiring). Instead, you should focus on audio mixer settings, selecting the correct input device etc.

Comment: @DanielB https://support.headsetbuddy.com/hc/en-us/articles/207970396-Smartphone-Headset-Standards-Apple-iPhone-AHJ-CTIA-OMTP As the article suggests, if it is using a different standard in the headphones, the microphone will be quiet or inaudible. On windows it is quiet, but I didn't think much of that it wasn't included in the question.

Comment: @Spiff The apple headphones use the CTIA standard while my computer uses OMTP (I think). Even if my computer does use CTIA, apple uses a non-standard version of it as suggested by the article.

Comment: maybe https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/audio-config/
say it if it actually works.